# Pug, Marked and NodeJs issue

Tags: node.js, pug, javascript-marked

I have a question regarding Node, Pug and Marked. I have one, specific place where I'll be adding reports and I'd like them to have simple formatting (bold, links etc).

It seems that everything is working fine but when it imports data from database which I import like that:

```
#{marked(meeting.report)}
```

But it seems that PUG adds < > before and after imported data which gives such output:

< **Meeting report** >

Could someone tell me if there is any solution for that?

Comment: What is `marked` doing?  What is the actual output you're trying to get?  We're missing some key details here in order to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I'm sorry I wasn't very specific! MarkedJS uses marked formatting (like wrapping text around ** some text ** makes it bold). I am getting the right output but PUG adds <> brackets and I was wondering if someone could help me with getting rid of those.

Answer (score 1):

In order to allow markedJS formatting, I used PUG's unescaped rendered code:

```
p!= marked(meeting.report)
```